# Bibliography fails ./main.aux:2: Undefined control sequence

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I am getting an error due to my references. It happened on my dissertation randomly so I'm not sure what change caused the problem but I am able to reproduce the error using the following  code

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}
\begin{document}
\parencite{BIM}
\end{document}
```

This is on Overleaf. If I include a .bib file it is fine until I name it the same as the document being added even if the bib file is empty. I have tried other methods of adding a bibliography too.
My dissertation is due this week so I'd really appreciate help because I'm spending hours trying to fix this when I should be doing actual writing.

The following also seems to produce the same error

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{babelbib}
\begin{document}
\parencite{BIM}
\bibliographystyle{babplain}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: I've just quickly tested your code on Overleaf, and things seem to be working well so far, so it *may* be something in your .bib file that's causing the problem (e.g. you have a \url{...} somewhere in your .bib file, but didn't load `hyperref` nor `url` packages). If you're still having problems, send us an email on support@overleaf.com with your project URL, and we'll have a look!

Comment: Any news here? The best we can do is saying that this should really work. We of course don't know your `.bib` file and don't know if you had any auxiliary files hanging about that might have caused trouble.

Comment: I have agreed with the close votes. Your problem has apparently been resolved, but from your MWE it is not at all clear how, as such this question is quite unlikely to help future visitors.

Comment: @LianTzeLim This question is tagged with *overleaf* but i am not sure if the issue was ever related to overleaf. There are many questions like that. If you have some spare time, do you mind looking through the list and retag some questions if needed? That would be great and users could find stuff better.

Comment: @Johannes_B OK, I'll have a look through when I have time -- so just to clarify, only tag with `overleaf` (or similarly other editor/front end tags) if the problem occurs _only_ on that platform, agree?

Comment: @LianTzeLim Only or *mainly*. Often it is quite foggy what really lies behind a question. :-) Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[LianTze](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/226/liantze-lim) Kindly solved my problem. The problem was with the .bib file